# How to setup Confluent on a 3-node Ubuntu machines

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-control-center

I was trying to set up Confluent (ZooKeeper, Kafka, Schema Registry, Control Center, Kafka Connect, Confluent REST Proxy, ksqlDB) on a 3-node setup (i.e 3 Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machines).

Can anyone, who has previously done this setup, help with the steps?

I was following their [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/zip-tar.html#prod-kafka-cli-install), which did not help much.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a replacement for a tutorial or following the docs as they're written. I suggest you use the APT installation, but you need to edit your question to be more specific about what issues you are having. For example, did you already get Zookeeper and/or Kafka working? It'd be a whole lot easier to use Ansible if you want to use bare metal installation

Comment: If you use Vagrant to manage VMs, you could also see if this helps (although uses CentOS). Haven't touched it in years though https://github.com/OneCricketeer/cp-ansible-vagrant